# Determining if a string is a double

Tags: c++, string, double

I would like to see if a string contains a double as its sole contents. In other words, if it could possibly be the output of the following function:

```
string doubleToString(double num)
{
    stringstream s;
    s << num;
    return s.str();
}
```

Comment: Check my answer if you needed:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39813237/4316802

Comment: A string is never a double.

Comment: wrongusername, is white-space, aside from the final `'\n'` , after and before the numeric text allowed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want the [strtod](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) function.

```
bool isOnlyDouble(const char* str)
{
    char* endptr = 0;
    strtod(str, &endptr);

    if(*endptr != '\0' || endptr == str)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `If no conversion is performed, zero is returned and the value of nptr is stored in the location referenced by endptr`. It appears I cannot utilize this method of detecting doubles if it happens to be 0

Comment: By the way, I cannot compile your code. It seems `valid` is undeclared?

Comment: I think there's another typo here: `*endptr =! '\0'`. Shouldn't that be `!=`? The really insidious thing is I think that might actually compile and run, but give the wrong result.

Comment: Damn skippy it should. Good catch.

Comment: `if (x) return false; [else] return true;` is better expressed as `return !(x);

Comment: Chris: it factors the code better: removes a **redundant** "return", the keywords `true` and `false` that are obviously the results of any logical test, as well as the `if` statement that also implicit in the situation. So, that proves it's more concise. I can not prove it's simpler or better per se - that depends on the programmer maintaining it. Still, after 28 years programming I can assure you the industry's expectation and best practice is that programmers should make the small effort to get their mind around the essential nature of booleans and simplify the code accordingly.

Comment: @TonyD: I disagree. Chris's version is much more readable, clear and maintainable. And I can assure you that the industry's expectation is for code that meets those criteria, not code that uses "tricks" to become as condensed and confusing as possible.

Comment: According to the documentation of strdot decimal point is local dependent. So it means that this function is intended to parse decimal number from user input, but is not suitable to parse some well-defined format, for example files. Imagine that you use dot as decimal point, but on Czech Windows is comma default decimal point instead of dot. So strdot will be looking for comma, which is thousand separator in american format. You will parse non decimal and completely different number instead.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: `return endptr != str && *endptr == '\0';` is not condensed at the expense of complexity - it's simplified.  If you struggle with that more than the `if` statement in Chris's answer, you shouldn't be programming professionally.

Comment: @TonyD: It's not about "I can't handle it"; it's about "I shouldn't be forced to". I believe we can discuss this without resorting to professional insults.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: I'm lost for words... you stand by your previous comment that *"Chris's version is much more readable, clear and maintainable."* despite seeing the simplified version in my last comment?  Professional programmers shouldn't need to be *"forced"* to make such obvious and obviously-beneficial simplifications.

Comment: @TonyD: Yes, I stand by what I have said. Insulting me further won't change my view.

Comment: @TonyD Please stop with the "real programmers" crap. There's a lot to be said for personal taste as well as cognitive burden. People are different and process things differently. Deal with it. I've been in the industry for almost 12 years now and I generally avoid working with people who express views the way you just did. It's anti-social and rude, and there's no technical merit for any of it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Boost [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) to check whether a string contains double or not.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp> 
....
using boost::lexical_cast; 
using boost::bad_lexical_cast; 
....
template<typename T> bool isValid(const string& num) { 
   bool flag = true; 
   try { 
      T tmp = lexical_cast<T>(num); 
   } 
   catch (bad_lexical_cast &e) { 
      flag = false; 
   } 
   return flag; 
} 

int main(){
  // ....
 if (isValid<double>(str))
     cout << "valid double." << endl; 
 else 
     cout << "NOT a valid double." << endl;
  //....
}
```

Comment: -1 for abuse of exceptions.  Exceptions should not be used for control flow, only for handling exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @Chris: I have, but not enough to adopt a python style.  Even so, what's normal in one language is a very poor practice in another.  Another example is writing C++ code in OCaml when you should be using list comprehensions.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : I think the code is perfectly fine and cleaner than the code snippet posted by Chris. `lexical_cast<T>(num); ` throws an exception on failure. I couldn't think of a better alternative.

Comment: @Chris: But really, it's catching an exception to turn it into a return value that's the code smell.  One wouldn't find that in python.  Either you have a language with lightweight exceptions, and use them to report failure, or heavyweight exceptions, like C++, where return codes are used for anticipated failures.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: cleaner how?

Comment: @Chris: Yours could be clearer by breaking the `if` in two, and comment each branch ("conversion failed" and "garbage following number").  But there's nothing wrong with it, high performance, and obviously meets the requirements.  Whereas it's not clear what `lexical_cast` would do if there was something after the numeric part of the string.

Comment: OK, well that's just a matter of documentation. Mine doesn't pull in the boost library which IMHO is ALWAYS the cleaner approach ;)

Answer (score 5):

You've been offered C-style and boost alternatives, but in the style of your `doubleToString` implementation:

```
bool is_double(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    double d;
    return iss >> d >> std::ws && iss.eof();
}
```

Here, you're checking `iss >> d` returns `iss`, which will only evaluate to `true` in a boolean context if the streaming was successful.  The check for nothing but whitespace before `eof()` ensures there's no trailing garbage.

If you want to consider leading and trailing whitespace garbage too:

```
    return iss >> std::nowkipws >> d && iss.eof();
```

This can be generalised into a boolean-returning test similar to boost's `lexical_cast<>`...

```
template <typename T>
bool is_ws(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    T x;
    return iss >> x >> std::ws && iss.eof();
}

template <typename T>
bool is(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    T x;
    return iss >> std::noskipws >> x && iss.eof();
}

...
if (is<double>("3.14E0")) ...
if (is<std::string>("hello world")) ...; // note: NOT a single string
                                         // as streaming tokenises at
                                         // whitespace by default...
```

You can specialise the template for any type-specific behaviours you'd like, such as:

```
template <>
bool is<std::string>(const std::string& s)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `is` be `iss` in the parts `!(is >> c)`.

Answer (score 2):

Or use streams directly:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
bool isValid(std::string const& num)
{
    T  value;
    std::stringstream stream(num);
    stream >> value;

    // If the stream is already in the error state peak will not change it.
    // Otherwise stream should be good and there should be no more data
    // thus resulting in a peek returning an EOF
    return (stream) &&
           stream.peek() == std::char_traits<typename std::stringstream::char_type>::eof();
}

int main()
{
    isValid<double>("55");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function that might help?
It also checks for typos like 12.3.4 or 1,4.

```
// check if input string is decimal
bool is_decimal_str(string input)
{
    int decimal = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (auto character : input)
    {
        if (character == '.')
        {
            decimal++;
        }
        else if ((character == '+' || character == '-') && index == 0);
        else if (!isdigit(character))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (decimal > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        index++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or

```
   // check if input string is decimal
    bool is_decimal_str(string input)
    {
        int decimal = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < input.size(); index++)
        {
            if (input[index] == '.')
            {
                decimal++;
            }
            else if ((input[index] == '+' || input[index] == '-') && index == 0);
            else if (!isdigit(input[index]))
            {
                return false;
            }
    
            if (decimal > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since no one else has mentioned it: the obvious solution is you want to know whether a string has a given syntax is to use regular expressions.  I'm not sure that it's the best solution in this case, since the regular expression for a legal double is fairly complex (and thus easy to get wrong).  And your specification is somewhat vague: do you want to accept any string which can be parsed (by `>>` for example) as a legal double, or only strings can be returned by your `doubleToString` function?  If the former, the simplest solution is probably to convert the string to a double, making sure that there is no error and you have consumed all of the characters (Martin's solution, except that it's silly to make it a template until you need to).  If the latter, the easiest solution is to reconvert the double you've found back into a string, using your function, and compare the two strings.  (Just to make the difference clear: Martin's function will return `true` for things like `"&nbsp;&nbsp;1.0"`, `"1E2"`, `".00000000001"` and `"3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937"`, which your function will never generate.)