# Convert java method into cpp

Tags: java, c++, qt

```
public boolean isDoubleValue(String s) {
        try {
            Double.valueOf(s);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But i want to convert this method into QT cpp.
Can any one help me?

Thanks,
Nagaraju

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932391/determining-if-a-string-is-a-double

Comment: I want it for QT. so better to use QT library

Comment: QT is just a library on top of C and C++.  Any answer that works with those should work with any QT compiled C++ application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need it in Qt (from your comment), you can use

[`double QString::toDouble ( bool * ok = 0 ) const`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#toDouble).

And you can check the value of `ok` and return accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

You probably want atof().  This is a standard c library function for converting strings to doubles.

Comment: You probably don't want `atof` because, as the manual page says, "atof() does not detect errors." If `QString::toDouble` is undesirable, use `strtod` instead.