# How do I split a string by space and change the data type of the string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have some arrays. I have to use parallel arrays, I cannot use vectors. I will check the items before they go into the arrays.

Input example:

> 23.6 Felix 45

```
double timeArray[size]
int playernumberArray[size]
string lastnameArray[size]

string = input;    
cin >> input;
```

How do I split up the input, change the data type, and put it into the appropriate array?

Comment: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) { if (!(std::cin >> timeArray[i] >> playernumberArray[i] >> lastnameArray[i])) throw std::runtime_error("input failure"); }`  There may be other relevant concerns, depending on the input format of the data, and how to recover from errors.

Comment: `cin >> timeArray[index] >> playernumberArray[index] >> lastnameArray[index];` But avoid ugly and unsafe things: (1) define a `struct` to hold a record instead of separate arrays, (2) overload `str::istream& operator >>(std::istream&, MyStruct&);` to parse your data and (3) use a `std::vector<MyStruct>` or the like for safe dynamic allocation.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I cannot do this because I need to check the items before they go into the array. Besides the WHOLE line will be 23.6 Felix 45 separated by a space. They will not press enter after 23.6 (enter) Felix(enter) so your suggestion would not work.

Comment: their suggestions will work if the user only pressed enter at the end of the line, but anyway, since you need to check them first then you should define 3 strings, and `cin` the input into each string and check each string individually, for example [this shows how you can check for a double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813237/15649230).

Comment: @AhmedAEK so I should cin>> string temp 1>>string temp 2>> string temp 3 check and put them into the 3 arrays?

Comment: exactly, also as pointed by the answer if you want to handle more complicated "input mistakes", you can use a regex for validation, which is a better idea as the input will not block until the user inputs 3 strings.

Answer (score 1):

iostreams' formatted inputter (`operator >>`) is designed to parse *whitespace* delimited text.  If you have input where the distinction between *different kinds* of whitespace is important (the difference between space, tab, and newline), then it is generally not what you want.

Instead you can read lines (usually with `getline`) and then break the resulting strings in to tokens, either using `string::find` or regexps, or even `stringstream` and `operator >>`.