# Getting numbers from user input until user types "quit"

Tags: c++, validation, input, while-loop, cin

I am working on a program to allow a user to enter an arbitrary amount of doubles, and add those doubles to a vector until the user enters "quit" which will then exit the loop.

I need this input function to not fail when the user enters a string or char, so `while (cin >> x)` is out of the question.

So here's my code:

```
vector<double> input()
{
    double x;
    vector<double> scores;
    cout << "Please enter a score: ";
    while(true)
    {
        x = checkInput();
        scores.push_back(x);
        cout << "Enter another: ";
    }
return scores;
}

double checkInput()
{
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    while(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "That is not a number. Please enter another: ";
        cin >> x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

This works, and will not break if the user puts invalid input. But, as you can see it will never break from the input loop. I need this to break and return scores when the user input == "quit". How can I do this?

Comment: Read using `getline()` in 1st place. Then extract with `std::istringstream` what you need to know.

Comment: Use getline() to read in an std::string and then use stod() to extract the double value. If it needs to keep working when it reads a string, then you need to use a string.

Comment: @JacobH I tried this method, but if the user enters something other than "quit" (which will break) or a number, then stod() will crash the program.

Comment: @Kenta : test if the input is valid before you use stod().

Answer (score 0):

Use an `std::string` and convert to an int

Here is a snippet

```
double checkInput(bool& dontQuit)
{
    string sx;
    double x;
    while(dontQuit)
    {
        cin >> sx;
        dontQuit = sx != "quit";
        try{
            x = stod(sx);
            break;
        }
        catch(std::exception& e){
            cout << "please Enter a number!: ";
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

in that case, your `input()` function will change...

```
bool dontQuit = true;
while(dontQuit)
{
    x = checkInput(dontQuit);
    scores.push_back(x);
    cout << "Enter another: ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool isOnlyDouble(const char* str) {
    char* endptr = 0;
    strtod(str, &endptr);

    if(*endptr != '\0' || endptr == str)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int main() {
        vector<double> v;
        double d;
        string input;
        while(1) {
                getline(cin, input);
                if(input == "quit")
                        break;
                // else it should be a number
                if(isOnlyDouble(input.c_str())) {
                        d = atof(input.c_str());
                        v.push_back(d);
                } else {
                        cout << "found no number in the string\n";
                }
        }
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
                cout << v[i] << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:
gsamaras@gsamaras:~/Desktop$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x px.cpp
gsamaras@gsamaras:~/Desktop$ ./a.out

```
3.14
foo
found no number in the string
foo2.56
found no number in the string
2.78
quit
3.14
2.78
```

The idea:

1. We are getting the input in a loop with [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).
2. If the input is "quit", break the loop.
3. Else:

   1. If it contains only a double value, push into vector.
   2. Else, inform the user.

I decided not to extract the value from w2.56, because it could be a typo.

---

Featuring this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932408/2411320).